# iText 7 add header and footer in HTML to PDF

Tags: c#, itext7

I want to add a header and a footer, which becomes repeated, to my PDF which becomes created by iText7 by converting the HTML.

However, all examples I found so far on the internet describes how to create a blank PDF by code with header and footer.

Does anybody know how I can achive this? I already tried to use the CSS print media queries to specify some areas but it seems those are ignored by iText7.

The conversion is really simple:

```
string input = "Bestellung.html";
string output = "Bestellung.pdf";
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(new FileInfo(input), new FileInfo(output));
```

bestellung.html is just a plain HTML file with some demo content.

Answer (score 0):

See [mediaDeviceDescription](https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/pdfhtml-configuration-options) under ConverterProperties.

> If your input file uses this feature, then you can simply tell pdfHTML
> to interpret the relevant set of rules:

```
ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();
props.setMediaDeviceDescription(new
MediaDeviceDescription(MediaType.PRINT));
```

Then you call the method with this signature:

```
static void convertToPdf(InputStream htmlStream, PdfDocument pdfDocument, ConverterProperties converterProperties)
```